# Enable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, gatsby, eslintrc

How can I enable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warnings in Gatsby?
My question is about Gatsby projects, I have no problem in React projects

I know that `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` is installed.In my `.eslintrc` file I added these changes but not working

1. in `rules` I added `"react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",`
2. In `plugins` I added `"react-hooks",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/fbuireu/biancafiore/blob/main/.eslintrc.js) you can find a configuration I'm using with `exhaustive-deps` and it's working. Summarized it looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    __PATH_PREFIX__: true
  },
  root: true,
  rules: {
    'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': `warn`,
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': `warn`,
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': `off`,
  },
  env: {
    'amd': true,
    'browser': true,
    'commonjs': true,
    'es6': true,
    'jest': true,
    'node': true
  },
  extends: [
    `react-app`,
    `eslint:recommended`,
    `plugin:react/recommended`
  ],
  parser: `babel-eslint`,
  parserOptions: {
    'ecmaVersion': 2020,
    'sourceType': `module`,
    'ecmaFeatures': {
      'jsx': true,
      'impliedStrict': true
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    `react`,
    `react-hooks`,
    `babel`,
    `promise`
  ],
  settings: {
    'react': {
      'version': `detect`
    }
  }
};
```

Make sure your `.eslintignore` is not ignoring your source files and your IDE is using the ESLint configuration by default.